# How do I configure psensor to only alert above a specific temp?

Tags: psensor

I'm using an old dual core laptop that's had temp problems since day one. It's 11 years old now, and the CPU fan is flakey at best.

The max temp for the CPU is 90°C. I've installed lm-sensors and ran the sensors-detect, hddtemp and psensor. Using psensor, I've configured the alarm thresholds for both cores to 80°C for the low threshold and 90°C for the high threshold, as shown below.

I want to be alerted when my core temps hit 80°C, That's not happening. I'm getting alerts when the temps are in the 70s. How do I get it to only alert me when a temp is 80°C or higher?

[Sensor Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3lWH.png)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that piece of info in all the details. I'm running kubuntu 21.10